# self execute function is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
var module = (function () {
    console.log('hello world');
}());
```

the above function did work upon loading, means it did self executed. but when I want to run it for the second time, I wrote `module()`, it doesn't work, why? I don't want to paste the entire function body to run it again..

I tried on angularjs btw, but either `$scope.moudule()` or `module()` work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-execute the result of the attribution, you're storing the result of the self execution (in this case is nothing).

Try this:

```
(module = function () {
    console.log('hello world');
})();
```

Comment: Every attribution return what was attributed itself. Mark as accepted if it solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

since the function is not returning anything `module` is undefined, that is why you are getting the error.

The solution is to create a function then executed it

```
function module () {
    console.log('hello world');
};
module()
```

now `module` refers to a function which can be invoked later

Comment: cant it be self execute 1st and then run it later?

Comment: @user3277912 why are you so specific about self execution? you can invoke it manually as soon as it is declared?

Comment: @cvsguimaraes sorry.. didn't see that you had already posted it.. +1 for you

Comment: @ArunPJohny just kidding :)